# Remove Lollipop status bar tint over color?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tinted-status-bar

Is it possible to remove the tint over the status bar color in lollipop? Currently, the bar color will change to a slightly darker version of the app's color.

Example of how it is now:

[image: screenshot of app with status bar tint]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I would like it the be the same color as the rest of the app, no darkening.

EDIT:
I've managed to modify Lolistat to color some apps the same color, my dilemma now has two parts: White status text on white text bars and the apps which Lolistat doesn't touch (ones with predefined colors)

Two working apps:

[image: screenshot of app with status bar tint] 
 [image: screenshot of app with status bar tint]
<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I know that's a decision on the app developer to use the default (i.e. a darker version of the app heading). Some apps like the Play Store 5.4+ don't do this, they have the picture of the app fill the bar with no tint at all. I don't think it can be changed without tweaking the ROM itself.

Comment: On my Play Store (5.4.12) the bar is tinted. I assume the "default" the apps use would be hardcoded into the ROM? I have xposed installed, maybe I could modify it through that?

Comment: It could be possible that way. Mine has no tint, only when an app opens and the status bar changes colour (using stock 5.1 on a Nexus 5). Samsung have a tint on theirs that permeates everything, it is ROM level (in the framework somewhere I think).

Comment: I think its like styles.XML and color.xml or something in my theme directory (cm12s)... After looking around a bit in those files, it looks like I'd have to change the primary-dark color to be the same as the primary color. Is primary-dark used anywhere other than the nav and status bars?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) (**needs root**), try any of the following Xposed apps which can theme your status bar:

- [Flat Style Colored Bars](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.bocharov.xposed.fscb)
- [Tinted Status Bars](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.colouredstatusbar)
- [Material Status Bar](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.vinz243.materialstatusbar)

They do it by taking a sample from the app's action-bar and colors the status-bar accordingly as per some mode settings, which include Gradient, Flat (which you want and the unpaid default), L and custom.

(**Note**: some features require an in-app purchase.)